# What is the difference between step_model and train_model in the OpenAI implementation of the A2C algorithm?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, open-ai, implementation, advantage-actor-critic

I'm struggling a little with understanding [the OpenAI implementation of A2C in the `baselines` (version 2.9.0) package](https://github.com/hill-a/stable-baselines/blob/v2.9.0/stable_baselines/a2c/a2c.py). From my understanding, one `step_model` acts in different parallel environments and gathers experiences (calculates the gradients, I think), and sends them to the `train_model` that trains with them. After this, the `step_model` gets updated from the `train_model`.

What I am unsure about is if both `step_model` and `train_model` are actor-critic models or if `step_model` is actor and `train_model` is a critic (or vice versa). Does the `step_model` use the advantage function or is it just the `train_model`?